# Is it possible to create a batch script with sql commands using cmdsql?

Tags: sql, batch-file, sqlcmd

I basically want to create a batch script that has embedded sql commands and I was wondering if there is a way to do this using cmdsql.  I'm using sql server 2008 r management studio and I've downloaded sqlcmd v2.0.

I made a batch script which attempted to connect to a database and execute a simple `select` statement, but when I ran the script it went into interactive mode after connecting to the database. It wouldn't execute the sql in the script, it would only allow a user to type in sql commands. The code is below:

```
sqlcmd -S <servername>\<instancename>
Select Number FROM Table1
GO
```

I changed the column/table/database etc. names as this is work-related but you get the idea. I'm quite new to batch scripting and don't have much experience, I have more experience with sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to feed input into a program is preparing the input and redirecting it via a `|` pipe. For example:

```
(
echo Select Number FROM Table1
echo GO
echo . . .
echo EXIT or QUIT or BYE...
) | sqlcmd -S <servername>\<instancename>
```

However, if the purpose of your Batch file is just to execute sql commands (and have no Batch logic), an easier way is to prepare a `.txt` file with the same input you would type via the keyboard:

```
sqlcmd -S <servername>\<instancename>
Select Number FROM Table1
GO
```

... and then feed that file into cmd.exe this way:

```
cmd < theFile.txt
```

In this case, don't forget to insert both the exit command for sql AND the `exit` command for cmd.exe!

Answer (score 3):

You could try to [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). A synopsis of the documentation is available from the command line by typing `sqlcmd -?`

To run a single SQL-Server query from within a batch file, using the default database:

```
sqlcmd -S <servername>\<instancename> -Q "Select Number FROM Table1"
```